# change a part of file via regex and java

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 different results betwin regex online and my java code.

My input text:

```
Examples:
    #DATA
    |id|author|zip|city|element|
    Odl data - Odl data - Odl data    
    #END
```

I want change `Odl data - Odl data - Odl data` (in my example) by `foo`.

My regex is:

```
#DATA[\s\S].*[\s\S]([\s\S]*)#END
```

I want change **Group 1** by `foo`

[image]

démo online:

https://regex101.com/r/Nq9fas/2

My java code:

```
final String regex = "#DATA[\\s\\S].*[\\s\\S]([\\s\\S]*)#END";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

I want keep the 1st line (|id|author|zip|city|element|) but my regex change all data betwin #DATA and #END

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Qllz0P/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to match what you need to remove/replace and match *and capture* what you need to keep.

You may use a `replaceFirst` with

```
(#DATA\r?\n.*\r?\n)[\s\S]*(#END)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qllz0P/1). [In Java](http://ideone.com/V5FzIM):

```
String res = s.replaceFirst("(#DATA\r?\n.*\r?\n)[\\s\\S]*(#END)", "$1foo\n$2");
```

**Note**: If you have only one 1 line to replace, use

```
(#DATA\r?\n.*\r?\n).*([\s\S]*#END)
```

**Note 2**: If you have several such "blocks" in the text, use a lazy quantifier with `[\s\S]` and use with `replaceAll` instead of `replaceFirst`:

```
(#DATA\r?\n.*\r?\n).*([\s\S]*?#END)
                            ^^
```